# How to use ActiveRecord where method with an array argument and nil condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Product.where(['color = ?',nil])
```

gives SQL

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (color = NULL)
```

rather than what I want, which is:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE (color IS NULL)
```

(`color IS NULL`, not `color = NULL`)

Using the hash syntax:

```
Product.where(color: nil)
```

gives what I want

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."color" IS NULL
```

But using the hash syntax I believe loses the benefit of anti-SQL injection that the array syntax offers.

EDIT - I omit to say that the condition will be a variable and will sometimes, but not always be nil:

`Product.where(['color IS ?',nil])`
does what I ask, but

`Product.where(['color IS ?','red'])`
for example will of course then fail

Comment: "hash syntax I believe loses the benefit of anti-SQL injection" - it doesn't

Comment: There is no parameter in `Product.where(color: nil)` to inject anything into

Comment: @Alex Ok thanks, the docs under Array explicitly refer to injection attacks, but don’t under Hash so I inferred a difference

Answer (score 1):

You're mistaken, it provides the same SQL injection protection as the array syntax.

```
main> puts Foo.where( name: "' OR 1=1; --").to_sql
SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."name" = ''' OR 1=1; --'
```

Rails is even smart enough to handle a list containing a `nil`:

```
main> puts Foo.where(name: [ 'bar', nil ]).to_sql;
SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE ("foos"."name" = 'bar' OR "foos"."name" IS NULL)
main> puts Foo.where(name: [ 'foo', 'bar', nil ]).to_sql;
SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE ("foos"."name" IN ('foo', 'bar') OR "foos"."name" IS NULL)
```

The hash syntax is superior to the "array syntax" in every way except flexibility when you need something it just doesn't support, so most devs prefer it unless they're unable to use it.